# filtering based on two conditions: values less than on matching dates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm missing some basic filtering know how. What are some `dplyr` or other ways to return the instances when `value` is, say, less than `300` on the same date, for both scenario `a` and scenario `b`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

scenario <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
              "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")

str_tstep <- c("2/29/1924", "3/31/1924",    "4/30/1924",    "5/31/1924",    "6/30/1924",    "7/31/1924",
               "8/31/1924", "9/30/1924",    "10/31/1924",   "11/30/1924",   "12/31/1924",   "1/31/1925",
               "3/31/1926", "9/30/1926",    "1/31/1922",    "1/31/1924",    "2/29/1924",    "5/31/1924",
               "10/31/1924","11/30/1924",   "12/31/1924",   "1/31/1925",    "2/28/1925",    "1/31/1926",
               "2/28/1926", "3/31/1926",    "1/31/1927",    "1/31/1928")

tstep <- mdy(str_tstep)

value <- c(260,396,348,347,368,397,418,419,190,290,504,323,800,800,355,408,250,365,222,
           299,504,323,800,397,288,800,387,415)
df <- data.frame(scenario, tstep, value)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `df %>% group_by(tstep) %>% filter(all(value < 300))`

Comment: thanks @akrun, though after using `%>% spread(tstep, value)` after yours, I found that returns 1926-02-28, for which only scenario `b` is less than 300 (no `a` counterpart).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check the input data earlier, I corrected my code to consider those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `filter` `all` the 'value' that are less than 300 after grouping by 'tstep'

```
df %>% 
 group_by(tstep) %>%
 filter(all(value < 300))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   tstep [4]
#  scenario tstep               value
#  <fct>    <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 a        1924-02-29 00:00:00   260
#2 a        1924-10-31 00:00:00   190
#3 a        1924-11-30 00:00:00   290
#4 b        1924-02-29 00:00:00   250
#5 b        1924-10-31 00:00:00   222
#6 b        1924-11-30 00:00:00   299
#7 b        1926-02-28 00:00:00   288
```

---

If we the number of 'scenario' are less than 2 for some 'tstep' and we want to filter them out

```
df %>% 
  group_by(tstep) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(scenario)== 2 , all(value < 300))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   tstep [3]
#  scenario tstep               value
#  <fct>    <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 a        1924-02-29 00:00:00   260
#2 a        1924-10-31 00:00:00   190
#3 a        1924-11-30 00:00:00   290
#4 b        1924-02-29 00:00:00   250
#5 b        1924-10-31 00:00:00   222
#6 b        1924-11-30 00:00:00   299
```

Comment: Faster than the speed of light. If you haven't had the comment I would've said that you got me under 1m. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do it (assuming I have interpreted the question correctly)...

```
df %>% filter(value<300) %>% #remove values 300+
       group_by(tstep) %>% 
       filter(all(c("a","b") %in% scenario)) #check both scenarios exist for each tstep

  scenario tstep      value
1 a        1924-02-29  260.
2 a        1924-10-31  190.
3 a        1924-11-30  290.
4 b        1924-02-29  250.
5 b        1924-10-31  222.
6 b        1924-11-30  299.
```

This will give you the dates that appear in BOTH `a` and `b` with values below 300 (unlike akrun's solution, which also includes those that only appear in just one of `a` or `b`).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Gustar. Which to accept was basically a toss up, but because sometimes there are quite a few scenarios, and sometimes with long names, it seems easier to specify with  `n_distinct(scenario)== x` than have to type scenario names 
individually.